# Retrieving the size or modification time of contacts database in Android

Tags: java, android, contacts

I am working on a simple contacts sync application. I want to know whenever the contacts DB of Android is changed.

I know that VERSION and DIRTY_BIT or ContentObserver can be used, but that is not what I want.

Please tell me some way using which I can determine the modification time or size of the contacts Database in Android.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to determine the modification time of the Android database. The *repository* on which the Contacts Provider is based is hidden to you. Today it may be an SQLite database, tomorrow it might be something else. The implementation details are encapsulated and hidden. It *appears* to be a database, with tables and rows, but that's just its interface. No part of the API depends on or assumes that it's a database using any particular software.

Similarly, the "size" of the database has no meaning.

The SampleSyncAdapter sample app shows how to create a sync adapter for the Contacts Provider. You should follow it; otherwise, you're bound to cause problems.